# Why XCUITest failing on captured flow in Xcode 11.4.1

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, xcuitest

I captured a flow on tapping a simple textview and to wrote some text in the textview. First the capturing was very slow and sometimes it skips some inputs also. when I am trying to run the test with the captured flow it is crashing on the tap() method of the textview saying

Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for Children matching type Other from input {(
Other,
Other,
Other
)}.

I have taken a screen shot of the error [image: this one]

Here is the captured code

Can anyone suggest me what wrong I am doing or how can I overcome this problem.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let textView = app.children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 1).children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 1).children(matching: .textView).element
textView.tap()
```

Answer (score 0):

The recording feature in Xcode is quite buggy, yet may be helpful to novices.

You should write your tests by yourself since the generated code is slow.

Read these articles to better know how to locate elements and interact with them
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement

In your case the code should be something like this:

```swift
let app = XCUIApplication()
let textView = app.textViews.element

textView.tap()
textView.type("Hello, World!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the recording features gives code that is a bit convoluted, or even results in UI elements that cannot be found, but it can be a good start to get some code there, and then you tweak it by hand.

The generated code seems to imply that it thinks your UI hierarchy is quite deep, is that right? I mean, multiple child elements of child elements of child elements .. ?